# How do you prevent glitches in Swindler's Den?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been asked by Saadia to kill Kematu, who is waiting in Swindler's Cave. I read that when this cave is re-entered after finishing the **In my time of need** quest, there's a chance the game will crash, making the Companions quest line impossible to complete.

What do I need to do in order to prevent this, other than saving extremely often?

Before entering the cave for the first time, should I wait until Aela gives me the **Stealing plans** quest? If I wait until Aela gives me her quest (let's say, 2 months in game time), will Saadia's quest crash?

I'm playing on Xbox 360, so console solutions are unavailable.

Comment: Have you actually encountered that bug?

Comment: No, I haven't, and I don't want to.

Comment: In that case I suggest saving and trying it. Worrying about every single potential bug in a Bethesda game will drive you crazy.

Answer (score 2):

I killed him then stole the plans just fine. Besides if you worry about all the glitches you will hate the game.