# What is the right order to play Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard, skyrim-hearthfire, skyrim-dragonborn

I've read in some Skyrim related sites that many players have had problems with:
1) **Items in their inventory that are related to quests but don't work as expected.** (Plantea's flute, amulet of Talos, the 4 little things used in The Lost Ages quest, etc.)
2) **Related issues to quest that requires an event to trigger it.** (The Lost Ages won't become active even when you read the book *The Aetherium Wars*. Another example is when you kill the Boethia's priest, if you read the book while it's on his body will make the Ebony Mail inaccessible at the end of the Boethia's Calling quest)
3) **Visiting places that store special items related to a quest or not talking to people that gives you quests before you enter and "clean" those places.**
Probably there are more common issues, but now I just remember those.
I've already asked: [Is it possible to play Skyrim without bugs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/138315/is-it-possible-to-play-skyrim-without-bugs). The comments left by Batophobia were useful and I hope I can explain myself better this time.
According to my own experience, those problems could've been avoided if I'd have known the right order. (Instead of killing everyone in a cave, first I should talk to X or read Y, for instance) So, what I'd like to know is the right order of missions.
What I've tried is to finish a quest as soon as I get it, but not always work: when I'm in the middle of a quest and I get another, and if I start the second when I finish the first, sometimes is too late.
I'm not asking about a specific quest, I know. And I know this is not allowed in this forum. If you find this question too broad, please let me know how I should ask, because I haven't been able to play Skyrim without these issues and I'm getting tired of them.
In [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/143607/how-do-you-prevent-glitches-in-swindlers-den) question I got this comment: *In that case I suggest saving and trying it. Worrying about every single potential bug in a Bethesda game will drive you crazy. –  kotekzot*. Call me crazy then, but I want a bug- or glitch-free Skyrim play.
I'm playing on Xbox.
Feel free to edit and/or to penalize this question; English is not my native language.

Comment: the beauty of Skyrim (and games like it) is there is no "right" way to do things. There are methods that are more efficient than others, but when it comes down to it. the only thing that matters is how YOU want to progress. As for the bugs and other issues... theres really no avoiding them... the thing about bugs is you dont quite know when they will strike.

Comment: @JLaBella, I appreciate your comment. I know there's no "right" way to do things in Skyrim: what's right for someone could be wrong for somebody else. Yes, I know that. Talking about bugs, it's just that I want to play it without bugs. And now I realize I'll have to learn to live with them, just like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UESP's [Quest Timing](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Quest_Timing) page explains which quests are safe to do at any time and which are best avoided until particular circumstances are met. Mainly you should avoid doing the Civil War quests, as they will preclude many opportunities and can be very buggy.

Comment: So, there's a kind of "right" order to do things. Skyrim is too fragile...

Comment: There's also a right order to load mods, and all the special tools developed to try and not make it crash. But if you get a degree in Skyrim moding from Whitehelm University, you should be able to add a number of great mods and also get through the game successfully. Just remember to save often.